# Create new table if conditions met

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

Write a query that will create a new table named ‘RecentReleases’ with CD code, title, artist, and release date as columns and its data, for CDs that were launched in 2017, else a message gets printed that reads: ‘No recent releases available’.

Data inside Table CDs

```
 INSERT INTO CDs VALUES
 ('CD001', 'Awesome 80s Collection', 'Various', 24, '1991/01/01', 'R99'),
 ('CD002', 'Anti', 'Rihanna', 13, '2016/02/01', 'R183'),
 ('CD003', 'Now 75', 'Various', 22, '2017/03/01', 'R140'),
 ('CD004', 'The Afterlove', 'James Blunt', 10, '2017/04/01', 'R140'),
 ('CD005', 'Oh My My', 'One Republic', 16, '2016/10/01', 'R151');
```

What I've tried:

```
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = 1
WHILE @i <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CDs)
BEGIN
  IF  (SELECT TOP 1 YEAR(RELEASE_DATE) FROM CDs) = 2017
    BEGIN
       SELECT CD_CODE, TITLE, ARTIST, RELEASE_DATE INTO RecentReleases
       FROM CDs
       SET @i += 1
    END
  ELSE
    BEGIN
       PRINT 'No recent releases available'
       SET @i += 1
    END
 END
```

Output:

```
No recent releases available
No recent releases available
No recent releases available
No recent releases available
No recent releases available
Completion time: 2020-04-07T00:19:16.0325100+02:00
```

Issues:

Unable to iterate through the records, if I remove the "TOP 1" from my If clause then I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The error msg is very clear and there is a lot questions & answers about it. Ps: **Do not ever** use `TOP` without `ORDER BY`. I just remove `database` tag because it's about db design (not related here)

Comment: Without the DDL to create table `CDs` it's hard to `insert` the rows you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the point for a loop here. I think that you can just use `EXISTS` to check if *any* record exists for 2017: if the check succeed, then you can run the `SELECT ... INTO` query, else print the message.

```
BEGIN
    IF  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CDs WHERE RELEASE_DATE >= '2017-01-01' AND RELEASE_DATE < '2018-01-01')
    BEGIN
        SELECT CD_CODE, TITLE, ARTIST, RELEASE_DATE 
        INTO RecentReleases
        FROM CDs
        WHERE RELEASE_DATE >= '2017-01-01' AND RELEASE_DATE < '2018-01-01';
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
       PRINT 'No recent releases available';
    END
END
```